# Discord.js - .then is not defined even though it's in a function?

Tags: discord, discord.js

After about 20 hours of searching for answers, editing the code, and trying new methods. I've given up and decided to ask here.

I'm absolutely sick of this piece of code.
What I'm trying to do is: 1. Wait for a message to receive 2 reactions 2. After 2 reactions, post message to a separate channel

EDIT: After some users recommended removing my stupidly placed console.log before my .then this code now proceeds to not wait for a reaction on a message and go through the entire process without posting a message to the specified channel
Please bear with me, I'm still learning.

Here's the code:

```
  client.on('message', msg => {
    const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '703033480090484756' && user.id === message.author.id;
    msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
    const starboard = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(0xFF0000)
    .setAuthor(`${msg.author.username}`, `${msg.author.avatarURL()}`)
    .setDescription(`${msg.author.content}`)
    
     client.channels.cache.get('714842643766444122').send(starboard)})
    .catch(err => console.log(err), ('Passed! Added to starboard.'));
    console.log('Added to Starboard!');
```

If you need more details, Please ask.

Comment: You're (trying to) call `then` on your `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on('message', async msg => {
    let rMessage = await msg.channel.send("Test Message");
    await rMessage.react('703033480090484756');
    const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '703033480090484756' && user.id === msg.author.id;
    rMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
    const starboard = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(0xFF0000)
    .setAuthor(`${msg.author.username}`, `${msg.author.displayAvatarURL()}`)
    //.setDescription(`${msg.author.content}`)
    
     client.channels.cache.get('714842643766444122').send(starboard)})
    .catch(err => console.log(err), ('Passed! Added to starboard.'));
    console.log('Added to Starboard!');
```

You used `.then` on your `console.log('Woah! Passed the filter...')`.

Comment: Yes, Another user mentioned this. I removed that to use .then on .awaitreactions. However, Now It goes through the entire code to the final console.log to show completion without actually waiting for a reaction on a messge

Comment: Edited my answer. If you write a message now, it should send `Test Message` and react with an emoji. If you click this emoji, an embed should appear in your selected channel.